# Visual SVN or alternative?

Tags: svn, tfs, bugzilla, visualsvn-server

We are currently contemplating migrating from TFS to SVN.

I have previously used SVN based on a Linux server, but here we have no Linux boxes, and no Linux skills at all, so we are considering VisualSVN Server.

Main questions are:

1) VisualSVN Server: Basic or Enterprise? We're a small team, so I'm thinking Basic should be good enough.

2) Bugzilla integration - I've previously found this invaluable - any issues integrating it with Visual SVN?

Are there better alternatives?

Update:

I have found [this](http://turngeek.blogspot.com/2011/04/mediawiki-bugzilla-svn-scmbug-tweaks.html) website which offers some assistance with the installation - question still stands though if there are easier options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VisualSVN is a great product, the enterprise version costs less than $1000 so you might as well buy it. The main alternative to installing manually is [UberSvn](http://www.ubersvn.com/) which also gives you a few more ALM features in a web view.

I've not used Bugzilla to integrate with SVN, but have used Mantis (almost the same but a bit more colourful). There's a [blog post](http://www.mantisbt.org/manual/manual.configuration.source.control.integration.php) about the svn integration with Mantis.
Alternatively, you could use a more 'featured' bugtracker like those found in [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) or [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). Both these integrate with your SVN repo directly, there's no post-commit hooks that are needed like you have with Mantis. The bugtrackers with these tools are plenty good, and they also provide you with project management features that you might find useful.

For the client, you will of course be using TortoiseSVN. This has hooks for [Bugtraq](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) so it can show a list of bugs in a drop-down (the alternatives require you to enter a bug number as part of the commit message)

I find that a Linux box is much cheaper than a windows one, and doesn't hassle you to update all the time. If you did decide to try Linux, then UberSvn would be a good choice.

Comment: These look promising - thanks. We'll check out the Bugzilla variants - anything to simplify the installation and maintenance really!

Comment: see http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine for a installed-for-you option to try out.

Comment: UberSvn has been discontinued.

Answer (score 3):

VisualSvn basic is ok, but the Integrated Security of Enterprise is really nice. (no longer changing your cached password all over the place when you change it.)

I don't know much about bugzilla integration, but it is mentioned in the [Bugzilla docs](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.16/html/integration.html) to use the [scmbug](http://freshmeat.net/projects/scmbug/) plugin.

Answer (score -2):

I have used Smart SVN as this client reminded me most of WinCVS client which I am used to.

Sorry I cant help you with  Buggilla integration

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that appears to be a client. We're primarily interested in the servers side - client apps are pretty much interchangeable.